# SVG gets blurry when other element in the page has a scrollbar in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg, browser

I have an SVG which gets blurry when any element in any place on the page shows a scrollbar.
The SVG has this aspect:
[Normal SVG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWFhj.png)
But when other div which is in another place, gets a scrollbar this happens:
[Blurry SVG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/913IK.png)
This seems like very odd and happens in Chrome, Brave, but no in Firefox.
Maybe anyone could share some thoughts about it.

I've tried making the SVG bigger in case it was a scaling problem but no luck so far.

Comment: please provide a [mcve] in the question, ideally as a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: Please read [ask] and add [mre] and you save your and users time

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? I'm facing the same problem. Blurred when scrollbars are present in content